# Check vs. Verify (technical/engineering documents)

Tags: word-usage

I'm translating a maintenance task report into Spanish and they use "check + verify" interchangeably in the source document.

They're talking about

> Checking the tightening torque
> Checking the pressure levels
> Verifying the voltage levels
> Verifying the charge level

etc.

Thing is, they mix "check" with "verify" in the same paragraph, which can be quite confusing. I understand that what they're doing is simply confirming that these levels, values, etc. are correct or according to spec, with no action involved other than reading, inspecting, etc.

Is it a matter of poor style or is there a big difference between both? Is it common to use "verify" in a technical context? (I think that "check" seems to be more common or at least not as confusing). I'm not a native speaker and would love to hear what the experts have to say about this.

I read this post and there's a few interesting comments:
['to check' versus 'to verify'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/to-check-versus-to-verify)

However, I'm still puzzled with this and your help/opinion would be much appreciated.

Comment: **Why** are you still puzzled?

Comment: The two words are synonymous in that context. My guess is that the author was trying to vary their vocabulary - which, as you rightly suspect, is not good style in a technical document.

Comment: Thank you for your responses :) Andrew, I meant that I am still puzzled even after reading some of the good commends in that post. JSheeran thank very much, that definitely makes sense.

Comment: @Carlos I know what "puzzled" means. What is still puzzling you?

Comment: @AndrewLeach with the difference between check and verify ;)

Comment: Ok. That's answered by the other question. You need to say explicitly what you still don't understand, I'm afraid.

Comment: I might use check for things that were set by someone and could have been done wrong. And I’d use verify for things that, if everything was done as prescribed, should be a natural result of those actions.  Check the fuel level. Turn the key and verify that the engine is now running.